# Custom Post Types - Capability Type

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I've been developing a custom post type plugin for my own purposes and I want to understand capabilities in regards to custom post types a little better before I move forward. Unfortunately the Wordpress Codex doesn't really clear it up for me.

I just don't understand what capabilities are actually doing in regards to custom post types.

For example, when I create a custom post type called 'book' and I use 'book' as the capability_type, it generates these 7 primitive capabilities:

```
[edit_post]          => edit_book
[read_post]          => read_book
[delete_post]        => delete_book
[edit_posts]         => edit_books
[edit_others_posts]  => edit_others_books
[publish_posts]      => publish_books
[read_private_posts] => read_private_books
```

Now, can I just create any kind of capability I like? For example could I do this:

```
[random_capability]  => edit_book
```

So that any user role who has the capability of edit_book can also have permission for random capability?

I've tried experimenting with it by creating two custom post types: book and fantasy-book.

I gave book that random_capability and then told fantasy-book to use book as its capability_type. Now, my understanding is that it would pull books capabilities (including random_capability) and give that capability to fantasy-book, correct?

In practice that doesn't work. I feel like capability_type should be pulling the capabilities of whatever type you give it, or create new capabilities if said type does not exist yet.

If not, then I have no idea how capability_type works and haven't been able to find anything about this. Anyone have any knowledge regarding this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you that the codex isn't a huge help on this subject. Check out the stuff about capabilities under [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) - it needs a serious rewrite.

As I understand it, only *page* and *post* can be used in the way you suggest (and in fact *post* is used by default in the absence of a defined capability type).

Of course, by creating your *book* version of all the usual caps, you allow yourself to assign capabilities specific to your custom post type, either in your own code or via a plugin such as [members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/).

You can create any capability you like, but I'm not sure you can do it at that stage. What I tend to do, is assign a custom cap to a role:

```
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->add_cap( 'access_awesomeness' );
```

I would probably do this on [plugin activation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook), as caps are written to the DB, so why do it more than once.

Your plugin can then check if the current user has permission to do whatever with it:

```
if (current_user_can( 'access_awesomeness' )) { ...
```

You can also use it where you'd add any other permission - for example:

```
add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, 'access_awesomeness', $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
```

I'm not sure that answers your question entirely, but that's my 2 cents worth.

Comment: So basically I should leave the capability creation to other plugins or somewhere else in the code. Should I still allow users to name their own capability types? like my example with book?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "allow users to name their own capasbility type".

Comment: I'm creating a custom post type maker where the user will be able to set all the settings of a custom post type via a UI in the backend. I meant simply if they would be able to replace 'post' or 'page' with anything - like 'blog' or 'video'